# PySerial write is not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I'm trying to write the commands to device and reading the output message using RS232 Serial port. When I try to write the command, it is working initially. After sometimes, it is sending wrong commands. For example, if I send `"PC:EXEC:MY_CMD"`, it is writing to the device something like `"PCPC:EXEC:MY_CMD"` or `"PC:EXEPC:EXEC:MY_CMD"`. Here is the code:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = 'COM11'
ser.baudrate = 115200
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.timeout = 1

time.sleep(1)
ser.open()

if ser.is_open:
    cmd = 'PC:EXEC:MY_CMD' + '\r\n'

if ser.in_waiting == 0:
    time.sleep(5)
    ser.write(cmd.encode())

if ser.in_waiting > 0:
    msg = ser.read(ser.in_waiting)
    print (msg.decode())

ser.flush()

ser.close()
```

I don't have problem on reading the serial output.

When I tried to send commands using serial terminals like tera term or putty, it is working fine. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Before sending a command you may have to flush input and output buffer, also check what line ending does your device support, in may be `\r` or `\n` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MichaelO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it on my own.

When I try to send my command, python is writing it very fast to the device. So I added a loop to write bytes one by one with small delay and it works fine for me. Here is the edited part:

```
if ser.in_waiting == 0:
    for i in cmd:
        ser.write(i.encode())
        time.sleep(0.1)
```